# Filter by last element in nested array in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

let's assume I have this object in mongo:

```json
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "Test" {
        "Array": [ new NumberInt("10") ]
      }
    }
```

Now I would like to use this filter to check if last element in an array satisfy my condition:

```
    { "Test.Array.-1": { "$gte": new NumberInt("10") } }
```

But it doesn't work as I expected it to. Is it impossible to filter by last element in an array or do I do something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain up `$gte` with `$arrayElemAt` in a `$expr`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$Test.Array",
          -1
        ]
      },
      10
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sO2E5JPsySg)

Comment: You can also use `$last`, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uMhuYRA7hXg), which is the same, just a bit cleaner (in my opinion)

Comment: @nimrodserok Thanks for enlightening me with the usage of `$last`. I thought we are only allowed to use it in a `$group` lol